# nginx 404 not found even all my instance setting and Dockerfile still the same

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I already deploy my project with this docker config and it work for so long now i need to add more instance on AWS so I use every config the same as previous instance but there alert `nginx 404 not found`

I not sure what i do after deploy or not can't remember but my first instance still useful

this is my Dockerfile and my docker-compose.yml

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: flask_application
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: flask
    image: myproject/test:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "prod"
      APP_DEBUG: "True"
      APP_PORT: 5000
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: test
      MONGODB_DATABASE: flaskdb
      MONGODB_USERNAME: mongodbuser
      MONGODB_PASSWORD: password
      MONGODB_HOSTNAME: mongodb
    command: flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0.8
    hostname: mongodb
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - ./mongodb/initdb.d/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGODB_INITSCRIPTS_DIR: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: mongodbuser
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: flaskdb
      MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER: 27017
      MONGODB_CLIENT_EXTRA_FLAGS: --authenticationDatabase=flaskdb
      MONGODB_DATA_DIR: /data/db
      MONDODB_LOG_DIR: /dev/null
    networks:
      - backend
    command: ["-f", "/etc/mongod.conf"]

  webserver:
    build:
      context: nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/webserver:latest
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "prod"
      APP_NAME: "webserver"
      APP_DEBUG: "true"
      SERVICE_NAME: "webserver"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - nginxdata:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - flask
    networks:
      - frontend

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
    driver: local
  appdata:
    driver: local
  nginxdata:
    driver: local
```

**flask Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install python3 -y \
    && apt-get install python3-pip -y 
    
ENV FLASK_APP /var/www/wsgi.py

RUN mkdir /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www/

COPY . /var/www/

RUN mkdir /var/www/apps/export

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000
```

**nginx app.conf**

```
upstream app_server {
    server flask:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    client_max_body_size 64M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        gzip_static on;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

**nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --update add nginx && \
    ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log && \
    mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ && \
    mkdir -p /run/nginx && \
    rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY conf.d/app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf

EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```